# AMQ Message Ordering with Exponential Backoff

Tags: amq

I am curious about the way AMQ handles message ordering when it comes to message redelivery and exponential backoff.

Say you have three messages: [M3,M2,M1]. If I pluck the the M1 message from the head of the queue and my system fails to process it, does M1 go back onto the head of the queue, thus delaying all of the other messages behind it? Or is there some some clever strategy where the message is put on the side until it is ready to be delivered, thus allowing messages M2 and M3 to be processed before M1?

Comment: Which version of AMQ are you asking about? 6 or 7?

Answer (score 0):

I ran an experiment and it looks like strict ordering is maintained. M1 will always be consumed before M2, and so on.